# iOS Display local notifications pop-up while in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications, popup

I'm having a little problem in my app : I use to send local notifications to the user when actions are performed in my app, while it's running in background. Notifications are displayed perfectly in the notification center, but there is no pop-up when the notification occurs.

If I'm right, apps running in foreground can't display pop-up on the user screen (only in the notification center) but when the app is running in background, in fact there is pop-up displayed automatically ?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : In fact, I'm speaking about a notification banner to be displayed too when the notification appear in the notification center.

Comment: It might be a little silly of an idea but maybe (just maybe) you want to share some codes in regards to what you did try ;)

Comment: Are you trying to get a system-style popup to appear on the device, even though the app is in the background?  The way you get a notification when the battery is running low?

Comment: My code is working, I just took it in app coda tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/                                                     Like you can see in it, there is a notification appears on the screen (on the top of the screen) when the app is in background

Answer (score 1):

When your app will go in background then you will see an immediate notification on your phone but you have to tap that notification to trigger didReceiveLocalNotification delegate.

If you receive local notification in foreground then didReceiveLocalNotification will be triggered automatically.

Above scenario is tested and verified.

Update: You must read this documentation: http://www.thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html

Comment: Yes, the notification is displayed right in the notification center, but there isn't a pop-up

Comment: In foreground can't display pop-up on the user screen (only in the notification center). Display only pop-up on the screen when app in background.

Comment: That's what I understood, but it seems to have a problem because there is no pop-up even if my app is running in background